# What is the phrase used here for "I have only a few days left until my holidays start" (with audio)?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, phrase

I was listening to [Coffee Break French audio, season 4 episode 18](https://coffeebreaklanguages.com/2014/07/lesson-418-coffee-break-french/). Near the beginning, the commentator says he has only a few days left until his holidays start. There is some phrase used like "je jis moins jours" or "j'ai J moins jours" (something like that). I would love to know what he is saying

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He says ***C'est J moins 2***, literally "it's D minus two" (only two days left before the vacations).

When English says 'the D-Day', we say *le [jour J](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jour_J)*<sup>1</sup>.

Note that ***jour J*** is not restricted to a military context. That might be any day when something special is going to happen, happens, or happened, like '**the big day**'. We also use the similar ***heure H***.

> Voyons, réfléchissez... Vous m'avez bien dit que A a été tué par B à l'heure H du jour J en un point P ? Eh bien, mon chèque dit : payez à l'ordre de X la somme de Y millions, signé Z ! CQFD.
>
> Pierre Dac, *[Signé Furax, La lumière qui éteint](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Lumi%C3%A8re_qui_%C3%A9teint)*, 1958.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>But while en English, D-Day was generic military jargon that was popularized after the 1944 Normandy landing and kept that single mainstream meaning for most native speakers, French can use *le jour J* for any event in whatever context. We might also use D-Day to refer to the same date although the usual term is *[le Débarquement](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9barquement_de_Normandie)*.</sub>

Comment: Wow, weird. It seems that this is used for more than the actual D-Day landing on Normandy, then?

Comment: @LukeSawczak Yes, *jour J* is not restricted to a military context, that might be any day when something special is going to happen, happens, or happened, like *the big day*. We also use the similar *heure H*.

Comment: Note that in English, we’d be more likely to say, “**T** minus 2”, using an aeronautical analogy (T = takeoff) instead of a military one.

Comment: @LukeSawczak In France, “jour J” is not at all associated with 6 June 1944. The expression has been around (both in English and in French) at least since WWI. In English, it entered everyday language very quickly to refer to that specific event. In French, it's more recent and means the day an important event happens, like “big day” in English. To refer to the military operation that started on 6 June 1944 in France, you'd say “le Débarquement”, or “le Débarquement [allié] [de 1944] [en Normandie]” if you need to be more precise. For the specific day, you could say “le jour du Débarquement”.

Comment: Indeed, French history books and WWII memorials sometimes mention the English name "D-Day", and I've never seen it translated as "Jour J".

Comment: That's very interesting. Whereas Google "D-Day" and you'll see it's all Normandy. So I think jlliagre's note that "when English says 'the D-Day', we say le jour J" should be clarified. I've actually never heard the generic meaning used in English because of the dominance of June 6, 1944. (But I do see that it's listed on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/D-Day#English).)

Comment: @LukeSawczak Clarification added, thanks.